# VB.net textbox scrollbar scroll event

Tags: vb.net, events, textbox, scroll, scrollbar

I am currently working on a VB.Net program where there are two parallel multiline text boxes like this.

```
-----  -----
|   |  |   |
|   |  |   |
-----  -----
```

I would like that when one text box is scrolled, the other is scrolled as well. I was wondering if there was a Scroll event that could trigger the change the position of the scroll bar of the two text boxes.

I was wondering if there was any scroll event that could be triggered or other ideas.

Comment: See [Scrolling Around with the RichTextBox Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7830/Scrolling-Around-with-the-RichTextBox-Control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that article that talks about syncronizing 2 Rich textbox http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=537285

I will need to replace my two textboxes by rich textboxes and handle the VScroll event from the Rich textbox

Thanks for the replies.

Regards,